# loading external geojson file into leaflet map by using leaflet ajax

Tags: ajax, leaflet

I am trying to load external geojson by using leaflet ajax.
I think the structure of geojson is true. This is the [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13312413146390895325) of it.
Here is what i did based on [HERE](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68489/how-to-load-external-geojson-file-into-leaflet-map):

in the head:

```
<script src="../external/js/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="../external/js/leaflet.functionaltilelayer.js"></script>  
<script src="../external/js/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>
```

In javascript:

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid',{ center: new L.LatLng(the_center_splitted[0],the_center_splitted[1]),maxZoom: 17, minZoom:11, zoom: 14}); //creating the map

var gs = new L.TileLayer('../external/maps/qom/gs/gs_{x}_{y}_{z}.jpg', {opacity:    1,scheme: 'TMS'}).addTo(mymap); //loading image layer

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("../external/map/qom/geojson/qom.geojson");

geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
```

But the geojson file is not shown and i get this error:
**ncaught TypeError: L.GeoJSON.AJAX is not a constructor**
I appreciate if any one can help. 
Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question and mark the code with the code markup syntax. See how to format section here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "functionaltilelayer.js" for? In the code Snippet you don't need that.
And `var gs = new L.tileLayer` with a lower t - change that and try it again!

```
<script src="../external/js/leaflet.js"></script> 
<script src="../external/js/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script> 

var mymap = L.map('mapid',{ center: new L.LatLng(the_center_splitted[0],the_center_splitted[1]),maxZoom: 17, minZoom:11, zoom: 14}); //creating the map

var gs = new L.TileLayer('../external/maps/qom/gs/gs_{x}_{y}_{z}.jpg', {opacity:    1,tms: true}).addTo(mymap); //loading image layer

var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("../external/map/qom/geojson/qom.geojson");

geojsonLayer.addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: I just removed that and tried that once again. There is no error, but the contents of geojson file which are some polygones are not shown on the map.

Comment: Can you show us the geojson file?
Maybe something is wrong with that?

Comment: I just posted that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems okay - did you import

```
<script src='leaflet-ajax.js'></script>
```

If yes, please show your whole code!

Comment: i have added <script src="../external/js/leaflet.ajax.min.js"></script>. is it diffrent from <script src='leaflet-ajax.js'></script>?

Comment: Double check that the file is actually being loaded by your web browser. Use the developer console and look for any network errors, or script warnings.

Comment: I just cheked the loading process, i corrected the relative address, now i have no error such as before, but, i the contents of geojson file which are some polygones, are not shown, yet!

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit tricky to import files via AJAX.
First remember that the relative path your giving the `AJAX()` method should be a Your Geojson file should be path from the location of the leaflet-ajax script file. (Since it is there the AJAX-call gets done).

I would recommend a different approach (without AJAX calls):

Your GeJson file (rename it to gejson.js) should look like this:

```
var json = { "type": "FeatureCollection",
             "features": [{ 
             ...
```

Import this file before your leaflet ajax code:

```
<script src="../../geojson.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

This will give you access to a variable called `json` which you then can use to import the json object in your layer:

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON().addTo(mymap);
geojsonLayer.addData(json);
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I am providing an alternative workaround.

Comment: @henrik thanks, but it want to use *.geojson file and ajax, not js file.

Comment: @henrik i just tested what you said. here is my Js file.

Comment: @keloniton I created a code pen for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoGZYv

Comment: @henrik it worked. Thanks. now, how can i access the property of each polygon? for example: "popupContent": "This is free bus that will take you across downtown.". Thank you

Comment: @keloniton Use the `onEachFeature` callback. Doc: http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson. Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RoGZYv